# VC++ compiler upgrade 2010->2015 redefinition; 'constexpr' specifier mismatch

Tags: c++, c++11, stl, visual-studio-2015, template-specialization

Working on upgrading a VC++ project from the VS2010 compiler to the VS2015 compiler and I've run into this error, any help would be appreciated.

```
C2475 'std::less<_Kty>::operator ()': redefinition; 'constexpr' specifier mismatch
```

This is the code generating the error:

```
bool std::less < sp < ref::db::string > >::operator()( 
    const sp < ref::db::string >& first, 
    const sp < ref::db::string >& second ) const 
{
    return first->cpp() < second->cpp();
}
```

Second example error:

```
'std::less<sp<ref::ifile>>::operator ()': redefinition; 'constexpr' specifier mismatch
```

code:

```
template <>
bool std::less < sp < ref::ifile > >::operator()(
    const sp < ref::ifile >& x, 
    const sp < ref::ifile >& y ) const 
{
    if( std::tolower( x->name()->cpp() ) 
        == std::tolower( y->name()->cpp() ) )
    {
        return std::tolower( x->extention()->cpp() ) 
               < std::tolower( y->extention()->cpp() );
    }

    return std::tolower( x->name()->cpp() ) < std::tolower( y->name()->cpp() );
}
```

Comment: Did you add a std::less specialization?

Comment: Don't specialize just the `operator ()` of `std::less`, specialize the entire struct.

Comment: ["The behavior of a C++ program is undefined if it declares ... an explicit specialization of any member function of a standard library class template"](http://eel.is/c++draft/requirements#namespace.std-2).

Comment: Well i thought they were already specialized, worked just fine with vs2010, all i did was upgrade the compiler, no code changes, I've added another example just for clarity.

Comment: @James When your code is ill-formed, your code can work.  And compiler upgrades can break your code.  This has happened.  Replace your ill-formed code with code that isn't ill-formed is the right solution.  Making your ill-formed code compile using minimal changes where it "works" but remains ill-formed is the wrong solution.

Comment: @T.C. - you're correct - but this is also kind of useless to actually understanding what's going on, given that the compiler doesn't warn about this kind of undefined usage.  The real answer is: In VC++ 2015 the `operator()` is declared (in `<xstddef>` with the `CONST_FUN` macro which in `<yyvals.h>` is defined to expand to `constexpr` - as required by C++ 14.  Thus the user's specialization doesn't match the template.  Which _is_ what the compiler complained about.  @Yakk is right that the _correct_ fix is _not_ to add `constexpr` to his specialization of `operator()` but to do it right.

Comment: IOW, the _language definition_ changed between the default language supported by VC++ 2010 and the one supported by VC++ 2015, and the OP's code, incorrectly written to be depending on undefined behavior of the language (though not diagnosed as such by either the earlier or later compiler), thus now fails to compile (which is kind of lucky for him, because it _could_ have just failed to _run_ correctly, by definition of "undefined"!)

Comment: @davidbak thanks for the feedback, unfortunately this is a monster code base that I've inherited so its going to take some time for me to get to this section and fix it right, have more pressing issues to fix, just wanted to make sure i wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks again.

Comment: @James so just add a `constexpr` to the definition of `operator()`, leave a `// TODO` next to it, and be on your way ....

Comment: @davidbak well, i was going to but it doesn't even look like there is a specialization for this, or there is and i just haven't come across it yet, I'm digging through 200k plus lines of very unorganized, un-managed code

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried with the usual pattern of specializing the `std::less<>` class (*functor*) with its `operator()`?

E.g.:

```
namespace std 
{

template<>
struct less<sp<ref::db::string>> 
{
    bool operator()(const sp<ref::db::string>& first, 
                    const sp<ref::db::string>& second) const 
    {
        // Your custom std::less implementation code ...

        return first->cpp() < second->cpp();    
    }
};

} // namespace std
```